# Font awesome font file not being loaded from custom theme in SW6

Tags: webpack, shopware, shopware6

I've installed fontawesome using npm into my custom theme. I have tried the following:

I have added all the necessary paths to styles in theme.json:

```
"app/storefront/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",
"app/storefront/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss",
"app/storefront/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss",
"app/storefront/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss",
```

and I tried adding the necessary files by importing in scss:

```
@import "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
```

I am still getting a 404 error in frontend.
`/theme/6bad85e1d79ce9868d87997e19558d80/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf`

Do I need to copy them into the project or is it possible without?

Whats the proper practice to add fontawesome or npm packages in general to custom plugins?

Comment: So you are asking how to automatically copy the `.ttf` file automatically to the `assets` or `public` folder from the npm package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the font files to `src/Resources/public/static` within you plugin directory. Ideally create a sub-directory for the fonts only like `src/Resources/public/static/fonts`.

The files copied should be:

```
fa-brands-400.woff2
fa-brands-400.ttf
fa-regular-400.woff2
fa-regular-400.ttf
fa-solid-900.woff2
fa-solid-900.ttf
```

Then in your `src/Resources/app/storefront/src/scss/base.scss`, or a `scss` file you import, override the source path for the font families.

```scss
// `swagexample` is the plugin name all lowercase, replace with your plugin name 
$fa-font-path: '#{$sw-asset-theme-url}/bundles/swagexample/static/fonts';

@import "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
```

Finally compile the theme and install the assets using these two CLI command subsequently.

```
bin/console theme:compile
bin/console assets:install
```

---

##### Update for webpack.config.js

You can setup a `webpack.config.js` to automatically copy the font assets to your static assets directory.

```js
// src/Resources/app/storefront/build/webpack.config.js

const { resolve, join} = require('path');

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@fortawesome': resolve(
                    join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '@fortawesome')
                )
            }
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            publicPath: resolve(
                                join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'public', 'static', 'fonts')
                            ),
                            outputPath: (url, resourcePath, context) => {
                                const buildDirs = context.split('/');
                                const parentDirs = [];

                                buildDirs.forEach(() => {
                                    parentDirs.push('..');
                                });

                                return `${parentDirs.join('/')}/${resolve(
                                    join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'public', 'static', 'fonts')
                                )}/${url}`;
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }
    };
}
```

```js
// src/Resources/app/storefront/src/main.js

import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/brands-400.woff2';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf';
```

Comment: Is there a (standard) way to extend the webpack build copy those files from the `npm` package to the right folder during the build? I does not seem right to commit 3rd party fonts to the local git repository.

Comment: I mean if you want to publicize your plugin, you'll have to include the 3rd party assets anyways, as you can't expect your users to install your dependencies and compile your sources. (node.js is not a requirement for production environments)  For the build process it makes sense of course to copy the latest assets over on building the storefront. I updated my answer with an example for a webpack config extension.